# Itextsharp display <strong> when I apply bold to a font

Tags: c#, itext

I am using fonts in this way:

```
PblackBold = FontFactory.GetFont("Verdana", 12, Font.BOLD, ColorBlack);
```

and I am applying the font as per below code:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(GdsPage.DinamycTextXx) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(GdsPage.DinamycTextYy))
     {

        Pchunk = new Chunk("We recommend checking your blood glucose levels at least  ", Pfonts.Pblack);
        Par.Add(Pchunk);

        Pchunk = new Chunk(GdsPage.DinamycTextXx, Pfonts.PblackBold);
        Par.Add(Pchunk);

        Pchunk = new Chunk(" and up to  ", Pfonts.Pblack);
        Par.Add(Pchunk);

        Pchunk = new Chunk(GdsPage.DinamycTextYy, Pfonts.PblackBold);
        Par.Add(Pchunk);
     }
```

and then I add the paragraph to the cell like this:

```
RoundBorder = new GdsPdfBlocks.RoundRectangle();
     PCell = new PdfPCell();

     PCell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
     PCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
     PCell.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_TOP;
     PCell.PaddingTop = 0f;
     PCell.PaddingBottom = 5f;
     PCell.PaddingLeft=10f;
     PCell.PaddingRight = 10f;
     PCell.CellEvent = RoundBorder;
     PCell.AddElement(Par);

     Ptable.AddCell(PCell);
```

However I get this as result

[image: Screenshot]

Does anyone know why `<strong> </strong>` is rendered?

apologies for wasting your time; I figure it out ; I am actually adding the `<strong>` tag "again" into a text string. Once I deleted the extra tag the bold font is working OK again.

Comment: It seems the Font.BOLD is not working as the text inside strong and outside it are same.

Comment: I suspect that `GdsPage.DinamycTextXx` is returning the strong tags as text. What exactly is the text there?